# Solr Shard Configuration

Tags: search, solr

Is there a way to configure a set of solr shards other than the querystring variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can also configure this server-side in the [search handler configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration).

Comment: You have to add a new request handler too.  otherwise it hangs.. (presumably because of a deadlock on startup with the parameter defined).